# How to get the JS request library to terminate request on receiving 100 response

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I'm communicating with a REST API that ignores most of the principles of REST and HTTP. One of the endpoints I need to use receives a POST request, responds with a `100-Continue` header, and then resets the connection on the server-side. It then goes ahead and performs the action requested.

Unfortunately, when I send this request through using the request library, my Node app hangs waiting for another response from the server. This is what my request looks like:

`{
    method: 'POST',
    uri: (host + ':' + context.port + '/xxx/xxxxx') || '',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
      'Expect': '100-continue'
    },
    auth: {
      user: context.user || '',
      pass: context.password || ''
    },
    body: bodyOfPost
  };`

What I'd like to get request to do is terminate the moment it receives a 100 response from the server. Is that even possible?

P.S.: Yes, I know and agree this 'API' is a complete travesty, but I cannot change it in any way for reasons too long for this post.:-)

Answer (score 0):

So we just worked it out rather horribly by setting the timeout explicitly in the request itself, so that Node errors out every time this API endpoint is used. Unless there is any way to override it, I guess this is likely the best solution.